# If a curve is hyperelliptic, we have an equality in Clifford's Theorem

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

I'm studying [Fulton's algebraic curves](http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~wfulton/CurveBook.pdf) book and I have the following question:

[Clifford's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clifford%27s_theorem_on_special_divisors) says that if $D$ is a divisor and $W$ is a canonical divisor with $l(D)\gt 0$ and $l(W-D)\gt 0$, then $$l(D)\le\frac{1}{2}\deg(D)+1$$

What I didn't understand is why if the curve is hyperelliptic, then we have $l(D)=\frac{1}{2}\deg(D)+1$.

The definition of hyperelliptic I know is $C$ is hyperelliptic if $2$ is not a gap (see page 111 for the definition of gap). The problem is I can't connect the equality of the Clifford's theorem and the gap concept. According to *my* knowledge it seems two completely different notions without any relation.

Any suggestion using Fulton's book level is very welcome!

I need help!

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

In page 111 it is also written that $C$ is hyperelliptic iff there is a degree 2 map from $C$ to $\mathbb{P}^1$. Having such degree 2 map to $\mathbb{P}^1$ is the same to have a divisor $D$ of degree $2$ with $l(D) = 2$. In the classical language people use to say a $g^1_2$. Now if you have an special divisor $D$ different from $W$ and $0$ such that $l(D) = \frac{\deg{D}}{2} + 1$ then it is possible to show the existence of another effective divisor $D'$ of degree $2$ and $l(D') = 2$ hence $C$ is hyperelliptic. A nice proof of this is by induction and it is written in the last two paragraphs at page 344 of Hartshorne "Algebraic Geometry".

Here it is a Fulton's level proof: First notice that Noether's reduction Lemma has a kind of converse (I'am taking 'almost' literally it from page 186 of Walker's book):

**Theorem 6.12** for any effective divisor $A$ and any point $P \in C$ at most one of the following holds: $$ \begin{cases} l(A + P) = l(A) \\ l(W - A - P) = l(W - A)\end{cases}$$

Now let $D$ the special divisor $D$ different from $W$ and $0$ such that $l(D) = \frac{\deg{D}}{2} + 1$. As Hartshorne we proceed by induction on $l(D)$. So if $l(D) = 2$ then $C$ is hyperelliptic by the very definition and we have nothing to prove. So assume $l(D) - 1 \geq 4$. Then there is an effective canonical divisor $W = D + E$. The effective divisor $E$ is a sum of a finite number of points of $C$. So there is a point $Q \in C$ which is not in $E$. Take now $P \in D$ a point of the divisor $D$. Now we apply twice Theorem 6.12 to $D - P - Q$. Namely, we want to compute $l(D - P - Q)$. One possibility is that $$l(D - P - Q) = l(D) - 2$$. In this case we have two times equality in the other one (just one of two must hold!). Namely, we get $$l(W - D - P - Q) = l(W - D) \, .$$
But the you can check that the point $Q$ belongs to $E$ contradicting our choise of it i.e. we chose $Q \notin E$. Thus, we get $$l(D - P - Q) = l(D) -1 \, .$$ 
Setting $D' = D-P-Q$ we can apply the induction hypothesis to any effective divisor in $|D'|$. Indeed, if $\tilde{D} \in |D'|$ is an effective divisor you can check that $\deg(\tilde{D}) = \deg(D) - 2$, $l(\tilde{D}) = l(D) - 1$ and of course $\tilde{D}$ is neither a canonical divisor nor the zero one. **QED**

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Do you know where I can find a proof more readable by someone who has only Fulton's book as background?

Comment: You said: "Having such degree $2$ map to $\mathbb P^1$ is the same to have a divisor $D$ of degree $2$ with $l(D)=2$", do you know where I can find this result? thank you again.

Comment: This is not just a result for divisors of degree 2. Without exageration I can say that this is one of the more important ideas of algebraic geometry. Unfortunately, Fulton tells you this in page 110 at the end of exercise 8.33.  I suggest to you to have a look to Walker's "Algebraic curves" page 140 paragraph "Rational Transformations Associated with a Linear Series" or also Rick Miranda's "Algebraic curves and Riemann surfaces" page 153 'Divisors and maps to projective spaces'

Comment: I'm trying to understand your answer. Thank you very much for your help!